# Can one have a two-sided matching market where one side is not restricted to being matched to just one of the other side?

Tags: matching, networks

I'm working on a problem where there are two sets of agents, S's and T's. Let's say there are 3 of each, so we have: S1, S2, S3, and T1, T2, T3.

- Agents S1 through S3 have a valuation for each of T1 through T3.
- Agents T1 through T3 have a valuation for each of S1 through S3.
- Each of the agents T1 through T3 can each be matched to ***one or more*** of
  the agents S1 through S3, and will do so according to decreasing valuation of their counterparts. (i.e. they will choose the S which they value highest, followed by the S with the next highest valuation, and so on).
- However, agents S1 through S3 can only be matched to one of agents T1 through T3.

Does this constitute a two-sided matching market? Usually for two sided matching, I've only seen each one on either side being matched to ***only one*** of the other side.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is called a "many to one" matching. Many to many matchings also exist.

Note that not all many to one matchings are a two-sided matching market. E.g., if I buy several oranges, that is not a two-sided matching, I am the only one with any input w.r.t. the matches.
Similarly, entries in different tables of a database can be matched one-to-one, one-to-many or many-to-many. However, there is no market here at all, just a mapping.

---

**Examples**

Some US municipalities use a many to one matching algorithm to match students to high schools. Since the preferences (rankings) submitted by students as well as schools are considered, this is indeed a two-sided market.

[The US National Medical Resident Program also does this.](https://www.nrmp.org/intro-to-the-match/how-matching-algorithm-works/)

Recommended reading:

[The New York City High School Match](https://economics.mit.edu/files/3024)

> Initial discussions focused on whether the
> medical match was a good model for New York
> City schools, or whether another kind of clearinghouse might be more appropriate. The medical match applied to schools would be a twosided model in which both schools and students
> have preferences, with the object of implementing a stable assignment, that is, an efficient
> assignment such that no school and student not
> matched to one another would both prefer to be.
> Thus, the question was, are the students the only
> real players in the system, with choices by
> schools merely a device for allocating scarce
> spaces? If this were the case, there might be
> appropriate one-sided clearinghouse models in
> which only student preferences determine efficient allocations (cf. Boston Public Schools;
> Abdulkadiroglu et al., 2005).
>
> Two things convinced us that New York City
> schools are a two-sided market. The first was
> that schools withheld capacity to match with
> students they preferred. Stable assignments
> would eliminate the main incentives for this.
> Second, discussions indicated that principals of
> different EdOpt schools had different preferences even for students with reading scores in
> the lowest category, with some schools preferring higher scores and others preferring students
> who had good attendance. If schools have different comparative advantages, allowing scope
> for their preferences seemed sensible. Also, the
> fact that school administrators gamed the system indicated they were strategic players.

Comment: A follow-up: Does the "stable matching problem" define matching markets? My model doesn't have a problem w.r.t stable matching i.e. agents can un-match and re-match at any time. Does that mean I don't really have to worry about matching markets?

Comment: No, not at all; but please ask new questions as new questions.